# Formatting json encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following php code that I am looking to put into an array, and then json_encode:

```
$teamQuery = $xpath->query("//td[@align='left']");
$pointsQuery = $xpath->query("//td[@class='sortcell']");

$data = array ();
for($x=1; $x<=30; $x++){
$data[$x]['id'] = $teamQuery->item($x)->nodeValue;
$data[$x]['Team Points'] = $pointsQuery->item($x)->nodeValue;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

The output looks like this:

```
{"1":{"id":"Team Query\n","Points Query":"110"},"
```

For the purposes of my project I would like to remove the line break (\n), as well as the leading {"1": in the code.

Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i very much doubt your complete output is like this.

Comment: i condensed it for the purposes of explaining

Comment: @user3468600 it's misleading and confusing to strip elementary things

Comment: @DanFromGermany can you elaborate, I'm not sure I follow. I will correct it for next time.

Comment: your output is an object, because you use an associative array. (`$data[$x]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to remove the line break (\n)

```
trim($teamQuery->item($x)->nodeValue)
```

> as well as the leading {"1":

Then don't index your array starting from 1.

Put together:

```
$data = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= 30; $x++) {
    $data[] = array(
        'id'          => trim($teamQuery->item($x)->nodeValue),
        'Team Points' => $pointsQuery->item($x)->nodeValue
    );
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Would you be able to advise as to how I could then echo json_encode($data); into a variable that will plot these values using javascript? I am currently able to do it in two steps: 1. Run the php separately and get the values array 2. take the values from the array and drop them into the javascript variable that is plotting them on a chart. I was hoping that dropping the echo json encode in the variable would work but it doesn't.

Comment: `<script>var myValues = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;</script>`